Can someone suggest a website which can solve $\Delta$ for a two degree curve / conic section?
For any two degree curve in the form : $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$
Here $Δ = abc+2fgh−af^2−bg^2−ch^2$
As I am currently working with conics, I often need to find the $Δ$ of a curve, which is a little cumbersome and boring when doing so for 4 or 5 questions.
Could someone please suggest an online site for doing so?

FYI: $\Delta$ is (a multiple of) the determinant of the Hessian matrix of the "homogeneous form":
$$p(x,y,z) := ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2fyz+2gzx+2hxy$$
(ie, what you get by replacing $x\to x/z$, $y\to y/z$ and clearing denominators). You could implement this in Mathematica as, say,
Factor[Det[D[Numerator[Factor[p/.{x->x/z,y->y/z}]],{{x,y,z},2}]]]/8, but I don't know of an online resource for such calculations.

I suppose I could just use WA to solve a 3x3 determinant, but I wanted something a bit faster. Thank you for your comment.

Too long to comment:
Run this C-code here and you can calculate the discriminant value;
(This can be improved by adding in a switch case which decides what type of conic and so on, but I believe that already exists)
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
float a, b, h, g, f, c, result;
printf("Enter the values of a, h, b, g, f, c for the equation ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0: ");
scanf("%f %f %f %f %f %f", &a, &h, &b, &g, &f, &c);
result = (a * b * c) + (2.0 * h * g * f) - (a * f * f) - (b * g * g) - (c * h * h);
printf("The result is: %.3f\n", result);
}

Wow, never considered using a program to do this. Could have maybe tried it myself in Java. Thank you.
